Understanding Air Pumps and Evacuated Volume in Closed Systems
Isn't it correct that an air pump essentially removes air from a closed space of fixed volume, which can be described as a decrease in the amount (mass or moles) of air in that space? What does the evacuated volume, denoted as ΔV, signify in this context? (The Question is from Irodov)


Your car engine has some number of pistons and some displacement (total volume of the pistons). Now consider how a piston (with appropriate valves) can act as a pump. As a side note, there are actual vacuum pumps that basically are a small engine block with multiple pistons.

I don't find the wording clear, but I think it means that after one outward piston stroke the air that used to occupy volume $V$ now occupies volume $V+\Delta V$. On the inward stroke, the air in the cylinder of the pump is discharged into the atmosphere, a valve preventing it from returning to the vessel of volume $V$. Then another outward stroke, and so on.

It's also not clear to me what they mean by one stroke captures the volume $\Delta V$. Each stroke is associated with  a displacement volume, which is not necessarily the volume of the gas captured by the stroke. It would seem that the gas volume captured by each stroke will be less and less as the vessel becomes evacuated.

@BobD, Some people in some circumstances find it convenient to specify an amount of gas by saying what volume it would occupy at a certain temperature and pressure. But in this case, where the geometric volume of the apparatus is an important variable, that seems unwise. The amount of gas (mass / number of molecules) captured by each stroke of the pump is less than what the previous stroke captured, but personally, I would go out of my way to avoid using the word "volume" to describe that amount.

@Bob D The amount (mass, or number of moles, however you measure it) of gas evacuated from the vessel by the piston stroke gets smaller on each stroke but the volume of gas evacuated on each piston stroke is always $\Delta V$ - the amount reduces because the pressure of the gas in the vessel is reduced by each stroke. Voting to reopen since the question is perfectly clear and has a straightforward answer.

@gandalf61 ok I agree to reopen

Suppose before a piston stroke the vessel contains a volume $V$ of gas at pressure $P_{old}$. As the piston is opened a volume $\Delta V$ of gas moves from the vessel to the piston. At the end of the piston stroke - when the piston is fully opened, and just before the valve between the piston and the vessel is closed - the gas that was in the vessel with volume $V$ now occupies a greater volume $V + \Delta V$ and so has a lower pressure $P_{new}$ such that
$P_{new}(V + \Delta V) = P_{old}V$
(This is where the conditions of isothermal expansion and an ideal gas are used).
So we have
$\displaystyle  \frac {P_{new}}{P_{old}} = \frac {V} {V + \Delta V}$
To complete the cycle the valve between the piston and the vessel is closed, the piston is connected to the outside atmosphere and returned to its original position. The piston is then disconnected from the outside atmosphere and reconnected to the vessel, ready to begin the next stroke. None of these actions affect the pressure of the gas in the vessel, which remains at $P_{new}$. So each piston stroke reduces the pressure in the vessel by a proportion $\frac V {V + \Delta V}$. After $s$ strokes the pressure in the vessel is a proportion $\left( \frac V {V + \Delta V} \right)^s$ of its original pressure.

If capturing volume indicates that the volume is increasing by ΔV for each strock, and we are assuming nRT to be constant, then what do they mean by evacuating the vessel if n(number of moles) is constant?

@RafatHasnain As the piston is opened a volume $\Delta V$ of the gas in the vessel moves from the vessel to the piston. The total number of moles of gas in the vessel plus the piston is constant while the piston is opening. The link between the piston and the vessel is then closed by a valve, the piston is opened to the outside and its volume is reduced back to $0$ again. The air (with volume $\Delta V$) that was in the piston has been removed from the vessel, so the amount of gas (number of moles) in the vessel is now less than it was before the cycle, and its pressure is lower too.

@RafatHasnain I have expanded my answer to explain the actions in the piston cycle in more detail.

"I get your point, but I'm still a bit puzzled about how this gas-capturing piston operates. Could you break down the process for me with a diagram showing how the gas is captured and released by the piston?"

@RafatHasnain See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piston_pump . It's like a bicycle pump except it is working in reverse - so instead of pumping air into the vessel it is pumping air out.
